# jquery mobile ajax uploading ok but inserted data do not show on page

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-mobile, mobile, load

I am new to jquery mobile and I have create multiple page and transition for them.
I want to load content for respective page when i change page to page.

Please help me, I only want to load data content for page.is this possible?

Thank and waiting for answers

Comment: There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.

Answer (score 0):

The guestion seems very broad and I am not sure what are you asking but since you said you are new to jquery mobile I was wondering could you mean how to change pages in jquery mobile when you have all the pages in a single html file? If so you can browse jQuery.mobile.changepage documentation [here](http://api.jquerymobile.com/jQuery.mobile.changePage/) and here is the code example to change a page.

```
<script>
    $.mobile.changePage( "../resources/us.html", { transition: "slideup", changeHash: false});
</script>
```